# Assetic Route Not Found

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I have a twig extension whose purpose is to collect a list of CSS and JS file paths given to it by function calls throughout a template hierarchy and then at the end of the twig template to take the output buffer and include these files in the `<head>` section of the page. For the most part it has been straightforward to implement.

In my service definition for the twig extension I am injecting the assetic.helper.dynamic service into it. The problem is when I call the javascripts() or stylesheets() method to get a URL for a CSS or JS file I get an error like this:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("None
>   of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route
>   '_assetic_bd311c7' not found")

service.yml:

```
admin.twig.asset_extension:
    class: Zing\Delta\AdminBundle\Twig\AssetExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
    arguments: ['@assetic.helper.dynamic']
```

In my extension I am essentially doing this to get the URL for an asset:

```
$assetic_helper->stylesheets(array(
    '@SomeBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.tablesort.min.js'
));
```

I don't understand why the router can't find the routes or why assetic is setting up the routes.

Comment: what happens if you add an output-path to the options array ? `sstylesheet('..jquery.tablesort.min.js', null, array('output' => 'tablesort.js'))` ?

Comment: Same error when I add that.

Comment: Same error means `exception Route '_assetic_bd311c7' not found`?

Comment: Could you please add the code of the class/service `@assetic.helper.dynamic` to your question?

Comment: Are you in dev or production mode? Did you try to clean the cache?

Comment: I've inherited the same site, hitting the same error, and haven't the slightest  idea how to resolve this.

Comment: The `@assetic.helper.dynamic` is a reference to `\Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Templating\DynamicAsseticHelper`

Answer (score 3):

The fix ended up being to run the following commands in the following order from the project root.

```
$ php app/console assets:install     
$ php app/console assetic:dump
$ php app/console cache:clear
```